# Fulltext show the matching word in a multi-word search condition with OR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a full-text indexed table and a column that is full-text indexed which contains a list of ids and some other information.

Example:

```
SearchInformation
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, Mike
200, 201, 202, 203, 204, John
```

And my full-text query (a simplified version) is:

```
SELECT searchInformation
FROM Table T1
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(SearchTable, SearchInformation, '"100" OR "110" OR "Mick"') k
        ON T1.ID = k.[key]
```

Now, this query identifies the correct row due to the "100" value being matched, but is there any way to show / select which value has been matched from my search conditions?

In this case, I also want to select the value of 100 from my query. I have looked into the Full-text documentation and I'm not sure if this is possible or if it is with maybe some additional changes in table and query design.

So, I'm looking for a result set similar to:

```
SearchInformation                    matchFound
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, Mike        100
```

I currently have an approach where each ID number is associated with Mike or John in a single row, like below, so then, after the match I can directly take the matched value from the ID column.

```
SearchInformation    ID
100, Mike            100
101, Mike            101
102, Mike            102
103, Mike            103
200, John            200
201, John            201
```

But I would like to change this to use the previously mentioned design, if possible. I know that the previous approach is terribly non-relational, but I'm curious if it's possible.